# Get a Parameter List from an SQLDataSource given Stored Procedure Name

Tags: .net, sql-server

Is there a sane way to get a list of expected parameters from an SqlDataSource given the name of the stored procedure assigned to its SelectCommand property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters method to return information on the parameters associated with a stored procedure.  Iterating over the collection will allow you to determine the parameter name, data type, direction, etc.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "myStoredProcName";
cmd.Connection = conn;

conn.Open();
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
conn.Close();

SqlParameterCollection collection = cmd.Parameters;
```

Take a look at the [SqlParameterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx) and [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx) class definitions for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do it in the ADO.NET environment directly, somehow - but you could always query the "sys" system views to get that information:

```
select * from sys.parameters
where object_id in 
      (select object_id from sys.procedures where name = 'YourSProc')
```

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I dont have VS.NET to try it out, but .Prepare() may do this for you :)

Or you could just add the parameters. :)

Answer (score 0):

And also with:

```
EXEC sp_sproc_columns 'YourSProc'
```